# Broadcom Wi-Fi Adapter not working on Ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, broadcom

wireless-info: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/w7nQFktm9P/

How i can get and install worked driver for this Broadcom BCM43142 adapter?

**sudo modprobe wl**:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='wl'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:990 command_do() Error running install command '/sbin/modprobe --ignore-install wl ' for module wl: retcode 1
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Invalid argument
```

**mokutil --sb-state**:

```
SecureBoot disabled
```

method links that i already try and get no result:

- [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)
- https://itsfoss.com/fix-no-wireless-network-ubuntu/
- https://suryanshpradhan.wordpress.com/2020/01/17/how-to-fix-broadcom-bcm43142-wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04-3-lts/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzYJqTLdYe0
- https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Install-Braodcom-BCM43142-Driver-on-Ubuntu/td-p/6978050
- https://ibcomputing.com/install-wifi-driver-broadcom-bcm43142-linux/

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. (Secure Boot??)

Comment: @chili555 question edited, I add `sudo modprobe wl` and `mokutil --sb-state` logs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The links you posted in your question suggest that you have tried several different packages and that, evidently, none of them are properly working. Let’s do some housekeeping and start fresh. With a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, please run the terminal commands:

```
sudo apt purge broadcom-sta-dkms
sudo apt purge broadcom-sta-source
sudo apt purge broadcom-sta-common
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If some are the packages are not installed and therefore not removed, that’s fine; just proceed to the next step.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
sudo apt install -y bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot.

Is there any improvement?

**Edit**: In our chat, we found that there were two additional wireless drivers installed. This is a possible explanation for the cfg80211 errors upon attempting to load the Broadcom driver *wl*.

We removed them both and rebooted. Your wireless was then working as expected.

Comment: Not working, i got this in log while `sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade`: `E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210209.1) focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.` while this commad `sudo apt install -y bcmwl-kernel-source` i got this line in log: `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Invalid argument`

Comment: In Software and Updates, please disable the CDROM as a source and try again. https://i1.wp.com/itsfoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/CDROM_Error_Update_Software_Sources.jpeg?resize=597%2C468&ssl=1

Comment: I disable CDROM and command `sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade` work's fine, without any errors, but `sudo apt install -y bcmwl-kernel-source` again throw ERROR line `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Invalid argument` and no wi-fi again :(

Comment: May we please see: `sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source | grep Version` We hope to see 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7. If that is what you *do* see, then show us a paste of: `cat /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/5.8.0-48-generic/x86_64/log/make.log` Paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/m4MzGBQdVY/

Comment: How about: `sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source | grep Version` Is this xx-0ubuntu7 or which?

Comment: `Version: 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122863/discussion-between-chili555-and-zeroone).

Comment: I followed these instruction but then got an error about the Kernel headers not being installed, so I did `sudo apt install linux-headers-generic` then it built and signed the bcm driver (I have secure boot so signing is needed). All working now. Perhaps edit to include making sure headers are installed?

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04, thanks!